# Drag and drop images in gridview in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-imageview, android-gridview

I'am developing a sample android application to learn about drag & drop in android. On start of the app, i'am displaying few images on a grid view. Now i need to drag one image at a time over to the place of another.  After dropping an image over another, the images should swap its places. How can i achieve it ? Please guide/help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve this by using thquinn's **[DraggableGridView](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView)**

You can add your custom layout

```
public class DraggableGridViewSampleActivity extends Activity {
    static Random random = new Random();
    static String[] words = "the of and a to in is be that was he for it with as his I on have at by not they this had are but from or she an which you one we all were her would there their will when who him been has more if no out do so can what up said about other into than its time only could new them man some these then two first may any like now my such make over our even most me state after also made many did must before back see through way where get much go well your know should down work year because come people just say each those take day good how long Mr own too little use US very great still men here life both between old under last never place same another think house while high right might came off find states since used give against three himself look few general hand school part small American home during number again Mrs around thought went without however govern don't does got public United point end become head once course fact upon need system set every war put form water took".split(" ");
    DraggableGridView dgv;
    Button button1, button2;
    ArrayList<String> poem = new ArrayList<String>();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        dgv = ((DraggableGridView)findViewById(R.id.vgv));
        button1 = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1));
        button2 = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button2));

        setListeners();
    }
    private void setListeners()
    {
        dgv.setOnRearrangeListener(new OnRearrangeListener() {
            public void onRearrange(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                String word = poem.remove(oldIndex);
                if (oldIndex < newIndex)
                    poem.add(newIndex, word);
                else
                    poem.add(newIndex, word);
            }
        });
        dgv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On clicked" +position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dgv.removeViewAt(position);
                poem.remove(position);
            }
        });
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String word = words[random.nextInt(words.length)];
                addView();
                poem.add(word);
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String finishedPoem = "";
                for (String s : poem)
                    finishedPoem += s + " ";
                new AlertDialog.Builder(DraggableGridViewSampleActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Here's your poem!")
                .setMessage(finishedPoem).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void addView()
    {

        LayoutParams mLayoutParams= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout mLinearLayout= new LinearLayout(DraggableGridViewSampleActivity.this);
        mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        mLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(DraggableGridViewSampleActivity.this);

        if(dgv.getChildCount()%2==0)
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.child1);
        else
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.child2);

        mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);

        mImageView.setId(dgv.getChildCount());

        mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), v.getId()+"clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return dgv.onTouch(v, event);
            }
        });


            TextView mTextView = new TextView(DraggableGridViewSampleActivity.this);

            mTextView.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);

            mTextView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), v.getId()+"clicked text ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return dgv.onTouch(v, event);
                }
            });

            TextView mTextViewLabel = new TextView(DraggableGridViewSampleActivity.this);

            mTextViewLabel.setText(((dgv.getChildCount()+1)+""));
            mTextViewLabel.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);

            mTextViewLabel.setId(dgv.getChildCount());

            mTextViewLabel.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), v.getId()+"clicked text ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return dgv.onTouch(v, event);
                }
            });

            mLinearLayout.setTag(mTextViewLabel);
            mLinearLayout.addView(mTextViewLabel);
            mLinearLayout.addView(mImageView);
            mLinearLayout.addView(mTextView);
        dgv.addView(mLinearLayout);

    }
}
```

Comment: I have created a custom adapter to load the images onto gridview. Could you plese tell me, how can i integrate this with DraggableGridView

Comment: you can do by Inflating your custom layout using layoutinflator.

Comment: Could you please provide any link/source/example?
I'am just a beginner in android.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done this : <br/>
private void setPresidentImages() {

  int images[] = {R.drawable.p_1, R.drawable.p_2, R.drawable.p_3, R.drawable.p_4, R.drawable.p_5, R.drawable.p_6};
  
  for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
  {
   ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
   iv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(images[i]));
   dgv.addView(iv);
  }

Comment: Now iam able to drag and drop the images. But i have few doubts.
1. How can i fix only 3 images in a row.
2. How can i know my images place on click of a button. After dragging & dropping, is it possible to know the position of each image? (i.e i want to know the position/cell_number of each image)

Comment: go in DraggableGridView class, see onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) increase colCount value.Yes you can know image index and position too.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i know the postion of each image? I have to show a popup if the user has arranged all the images correctly.

Comment: Please help me. Could you please tell me how can i show a background view for all images. I just need to show the number of each image postion in the background when the user picks up it to drag. The Background view (which represents postion of image) shoud not move when we picks up the image. Sorry for my english.

Comment: you mean to say that user can move the image but label(position in background) should remain as it is. For that you need to create your own logic AND IT IS POSSIBLE.

Comment: When I use the code from your answer, no items show up on the grid. Using the original demo code it works fine. Anytime I try to add a view that is a layout instead of just an Image or Text view nothing shows up.

Comment: In the thquinn's DraggableGridView when the images are swapped or dragged or dropped, they can be done in the single view only, my requirement is I want to enable drag and dropped to the other pages also. i.e when the user drags it out of the page there should be another page/view visible

Comment: addview() doesn't really add the view on the screen i have tried with layout inflater also but no item show up on the screen

Comment: i have same problem with DraggableGridView  when i am inflating a view 
no thing show now it adds single child.

Comment: Did anyone found the solution for that please tell me