# missing ImageView sources the first time i Drag and Drop in my GridView

Tags: android, gridview, drag-and-drop

I made a drag and drop GridView. Everything works perfectly except for the first drag and drop. I cant find the reason why it only happens the first time.

The first time I drag a item over the other items in the gridview, the imageview sources of the items are lost. When I drop it the sources will be fixed.. After that every thing will work just normal. Any idea how I can fix this or the cause of the strange behavior?

here is my touchListener which will handle the drag and drop:

```
mGridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                GridView parent = (GridView) v;

                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                int position = parent.pointToPosition(x, y);
                if (position > AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {

                    int count = parent.getChildCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        View curr = parent.getChildAt(i);
                        curr.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

                                boolean result = true;
                                int action = event.getAction();
                                switch (action) {
                                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                                    break;
                                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                                    break;
                                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:    
                                    setBlueFilterOnImageView((ImageView) v, getActivity());
                                    break;
                                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                                    clearColorFilterOnImageView((ImageView) v);
                                    break;
                                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                                    if (event.getLocalState() == v) {
                                        result = false;
                                    } else {
                                        
                                        View droped = (View) event.getLocalState();

                                        View target = v;
                                        
                                        app.myProfile().removeProfilePhotoAtIndex(((DragGridItemHolder) droped.getTag()).position);
                                        app.myProfile().insertProfilePhoto(((DragGridItemHolder) droped.getTag()).id, ((DragGridItemHolder) target.getTag()).position);
                                        
                                        
                                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                                    clearColorFilterOnImageView((ImageView) v);     
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    result = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                                return result;
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    int relativePosition = position - parent.getFirstVisiblePosition();


                    View target = (View) parent.getChildAt(relativePosition);
                    
                    DragGridItemHolder holder = (DragGridItemHolder) target.getTag();
                    String text = holder.id;
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("DragData", text);
                    target.startDrag(data, new View.DragShadowBuilder(target), target, 0);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

```
public static void setBlueFilterOnImageView(ImageView imageView, Context context){
    PorterDuffColorFilter blueFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(
            context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grid_state_focused),
            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    imageView.setColorFilter(blueFilter);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
            R.color.grid_state_pressed));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by these two statements: "the imageview sources of the items are lost" and "When i drop it the sources will be fixed"

Comment: The views are imageviews. When i drag a imageview over  some other imageviews, those imageviews will stop showing there picture (the image i've set as the source of the imageview). As soon i will drop the imageview, notifyDataSetChanged() on the gridview adapter will be called and all pictures are shown again. After that everything works just normal and pictures wont disappear. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What are you doing in `setBlueFilterOnImageView`?

Comment: see above, i've added the setBlueFilterOnImageView method

Comment: A i think it has something to do with the colorfilter. The images of the imageviews aren't disappearing if i don't call setColorFilter. But what can i do to solve this?

Comment: The ImageViews simply loose their images(blank item) or something else?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about GridView parent = (GridView) v;
This v is the view you want to drag, then why it is a parent. And after that you use parent.getChildAt(..) to get the child view. So why the container of the dragged item is one of the child view of this dragged item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly found a work around. So the problem is when i set a Color Filter in DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED, the ImageView source will be gone. To avoid this, i reset the source when i set a color filter. Not a very clean solution, but it worked for me.. Thnx for all the help

Answer (score 1):

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846240/drag-and-drop-images-in-gridview-in-android) releated to your query may be it will help you. Its too hard to understand your long code so try to manage from this link.

May be issue is in `mGridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() ...` once try to do like `mGridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several problems in your code:

a. Your onTouch method always return false, which generally means the listener has not consumed the event yet. So you should return true after

```
target.startDrag(data, new View.DragShadowBuilder(target), target, 0);
```

b. You put the onDragListener registration into the handling method of onTouch event, which I think might be the main cause to this problem. When you drop a dragged item, the onDragListener might have not been registered. Since your listener registration not depends on the source view, you can directly register onDragListener. And make the code look like this:

```
mGridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

};

for(View view : ...){
    view.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        //put your implementation here
    }
}
```

Comment: THnx for your help.. I got my code now looking like above, but still same behavior..