# how to drop an image from gallery view to gridview

Tags: android, gridview, gallery, custom-adapter

Can anyone tell me the way how to drag a image form gallery view and drop that in a grid view in android. Is that possible. My requirement is, I have an image and I break them in to some pieces, by using custom adapter place all those images in a gallery view, now drag those images in the galley drop that on the grid view on the same screen. Below image can give clear  picture to you. Provide me the way how to do that.[image]

Comment: Kindly go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846240/drag-and-drop-images-in-gridview-in-android .hope you will get ur answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me the way how to drag a image form gallery view and
>   drop that in a grid view in android. Is that possible.

Yes that is possible. Use [Android drag/drop framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) that will allow your users to move data from one View to another View in the current layout using a graphical drag and drop gesture.

This [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/drag-and-drop/android-drag-and-drop-example/) might help you.

Explanation :

When you drop the image to new location

1. Remove that view form its parent (Galleryview in your case)
2. Add that view to your new Parent (GridView in your case)
3. Update the corresponding adapters with data.

eg.

```
     case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
          ViewGroup oldParent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
          oldParent.removeView(view);
          GridView container = (GridView) layoutview;
          container.addView(view);
          view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          break;
```